# How to post more than 1 var’s with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been googling for a way to do this but everything I have found doesn't help me.
I'm not sure how to post all the below variables, If I select only one of them it'll post just fine as well as putting it into the correct database column.

any help would be much appreciated.

```
        function submit() {
      var mm10  = $('#10MM'),
          mm16  = $('#16MM'),
          mm7   = $('#7MM'),
          mm2   = $('#2MM'),
          fines = $('#Fines'),
          bark  = $('#Bark'),
          cqi   = $('#CQI');

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "classes/Post/ChipSubmit.php",
        data: ,
        success: function(){
            $("#successMessage").show();
        }
      });
    };
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in two ways. One using arrays, or two using objects:

```js
function submit() {
  var mm10 = $('#10MM').val(),
    mm16 = $('#16MM').val(),
    mm7 = $('#7MM').val(),
    mm2 = $('#2MM').val(),
    fines = $('#Fines').val(),
    bark = $('#Bark').val(),
    cqi = $('#CQI').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "classes/Post/ChipSubmit.php",
    data: [mm10, mm16, mm7, mm2, fines, bark, cqi],
    success: function() {
      $("#successMessage").show();
    }
  });
} // Also you don't need a semicolon here.
```

Also you don't need a semicolon at the end of the function.

Using arrays is easier, if you want more precision, use objects:

```js
function submit() {
  var mm10 = $('#10MM').val(),
    mm16 = $('#16MM').val(),
    mm7 = $('#7MM').val(),
    mm2 = $('#2MM').val(),
    fines = $('#Fines').val(),
    bark = $('#Bark').val(),
    cqi = $('#CQI').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "classes/Post/ChipSubmit.php",
    data: {
      "mm10": mm10,
      "mm16": mm16,
      "mm7": mm7,
      "mm2": mm2,
      "fines": fines,
      "bark": bark,
      "cqi": cqi
    },
    success: function() {
      $("#successMessage").show();
    }
  });
} // Also you don't need a semicolon here.
```

And in the server side, you can get them through the `$_POST` super-global. Use `var_dump($_POST)` to find out what has it got.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of like Praveen Kumar suggested, you can create an object. One thing I was curious about, it looks like you're passing jQuery objects as your data? If that's the case, `$_POST` is going to say something like `[object][Object]` or, for me it throws TypeError and breaks everything.

```
var form_data = {};

 form_data.mm10 = $('#10MM').val(); // Input from a form
 form_data.mm16 = $('#16MM').val(); // Input from a form
 form_data.mm7 = $('#7MM').val(); // Input from a form
 form_data.mm2 = $('#2MM').text(); // Text from a div
 form_data.fines = $('#Fines').text();
 form_data.bark = $('#Bark').text();
 form_data.cqi = $('#CQI').text();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "classes/Post/ChipSubmit.php",
    data: form_data,
    success: function() {
      alert('success');
    }
  });
}
```

Then to get those values in your PHP you'd use:

```
$_POST[mm10] // This contains '10MM' or the value from that input field
$_POST[mm16] // This contains '16MM' or the value from that input field
$_POST[mm7] // This contains '7MM' or the value from that input field
$_POST[mm2] // This contains '2MM' or the value from that input field
And so on...
```

I tried to put together [a jsFiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/q0h6vxqb/1/), though it doesn't show the PHP portion. After you click `submit` view the console to see the data posted.